# Connect UITableView DataSource/Delegate to base UIViewController class

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm attempting to connect my UITableView's DataSource and Delegate to my ViewController's base class via the storyboard. I Was able to connect my IBActions and IBOutlets easily, but this is proving trickier.

Is the correct method to instantiate the delegate/datasource methods then call the same methods on super?

TIA

Comment: ctrahey's answer below is correct, and I will mark it as such - however the one piece missing from the answer is that all you need to do is set the delegate/datasource as the actual view controler - since it has access to the functions of the base class. There was another issue preventing my list from working.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Xcode will type-check the objects you attempt to connect. So there are two pre-requisites:

1. An object of your class must "be present" in the storyboard, which usually involves setting a custom class on a UIViewController in the inspector
2. The class of your object must declare that it conforms to the correct protocols before you make the connections.

If those two criteria are met, you should be able to ctrl-click on the UITableViewController, and drag from these connections to an object of your class, either in the storyboard or in the list of objects on the left.

EDIT: I have added a picture of setting the delegates via the two-step method of ctrl-clicking the table view, then dragging from the popover to the protocol-conforming view controller. This technique works with both the list view on the left as well as the graphical representations in the workspace.

[image: Setting a table view's delegates]

Comment: If I'm reading you right, I would disagree with your first point - You can connect items to classes not in the storyboard or inspector, if they are a base class of your vc. I do this by showing the assistant editor, then manually selecting the base class for my view controller. I can then ctrl+click to that class. If I misread you my apologies. The ability I just described however makes me wonder if there isn't a way to set up delegates and datasources that way as well. I am declaring the proper protocols, on both the base and child class, but I'm not sure it's necessary on the child class.

Comment: For clarification, what you describe, "I do this by showing the assistant editor, then manually selecting the base class for my view controller", is exactly what I mean by making an object of your class "be present" in the storyboard.

Comment: Ah, fair enough. It's possible that I simply don't know where to drop the ctrl+click - with delegates/datasources there's no IBAction or IBOutlet created in the .h file - as you say, normally I would use the inspector and drop it on my view controller. With that not being an option though, where else could I drop it?

Comment: Added a comment to my question. Thanks @ctrahey

Comment: What I usually do is CTRL-drag from the table view to the view controller which adheres to the protocol. When I let go, there is a popover to choose which of the table view's delegates for the assignment. I do it once each for datasource and delegate. Keep in mind that the @properties being set here are on the TableView, not on your controller. It is the table view that points to you, not the other way around.

Comment: I have edited my answer to add a graphic showing how I set these delegates.